# C# gtk making widgets invisible

Tags: c#, gtk

I'm currently having a small problem in Xamarin while doing my interface, I have an app that requires certain buttons to be visible from an array of buttons, but I don't want them removed. Is there a way to hide them? I've tried with button.Visible = false but doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance. Right now I'm using button.Sensitive =false, but that's not what I  need.

```
for(j = 0;j<16;j++){
        if(i<outNumber && j<Math.Pow(2,inNumber)){
                    //I need this to make the button invisible instead of "insensitive"
            button[i,j].Sensitive = true;
                }
        else{
            button[i,j].Sensitive = false;
                }
```